# How to subset a dataframe in r based on an observation whose cell has more than one value separated by commas?

Tags: r, subset

I'm fairly new to R and programming in general so please bear with me.

I have a very large dataset (100,000+ observations). I would like to subset this dataset based on the value on one particular column. The problem I'm confronting is that the individual cells of my column of interest can take on multiple values at once all separated by a commas. For example Say I have a dataset 'm':

```
row1<-c('1','Jon,Ryan,Lilly','Soccer','3')
row2<-c('2','Carol,Ben,Peter','Soccer','6')
row3<-c('3','Ben,Carol,Billy','Soccer','5')
row4<-c('4','Felix,Jon,Casper','Soccer','3')

m<-rbind(row1,row2,row3,row4)
colnames(m)<-c('ID','Name','Event','Duration')
rownames(m)<-c(1,2,3,4)

print(m)

  ID    Name     Event    Duration
1 "1" "Jon,Ryan, Lilly"    "Soccer" "3"     
2 "2" "Carol, Ben, Peter"  "Soccer" "6"     
3 "3" "Ben, Carol, Billy"  "Soccer" "5"     
4 "4" "Felix, Jon, Casper" "Soccer" "3"
```

How do I subset 'm' such that R only returns observations for which Name column is equal to 'Jon'. I've tried

```
subset(data, Name=='Jon')
```

but that only returns fields where 'Jon' is the only name listed. I know using `colsplit` from reshape can create a new column from these different elements but some of cells have a different number of columns and some have over 10 elements and in all there are over 100 different unique names across all the cells. Is their a command in R that can subset based on a 'subset' of the string of names? Something as simple as the subset function but that queries parts of a string as well. Thanks to everyone in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for Jon with this code and return a boolean.

```
m.df <- as.data.frame(m)
m.df$Name <- as.character(m.df$Name)
m.df$new <- str_detect(m.df$Name, "Jon")

> m.df
  ID             Name  Event Duration   new
1  1   Jon,Ryan,Lilly Soccer        3  TRUE
2  2  Carol,Ben,Peter Soccer        6 FALSE
3  3  Ben,Carol,Billy Soccer        5 FALSE
4  4 Felix,Jon,Casper Soccer        3  TRUE
```

## Responding to the comment

Here is a hack to search multiple name columns.  Combine as many columns as you want to search, and then use the same code on the combo column.

Assuming you have another column called NameTwo -

```
m.df$combo <- paste(m.df$Name, m.df$NameTwo, sep = ",")
m.df$new <- str_detect(m.df$combo, "Jon")
```

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out this works too:

m <- m[grep("Jon", m$Name), ]

Is there a way to generalize your code or the line of code above to include the same conditions but for multiple columns, say for for example there was another column labeled Name2 I tried this

m <- m[grep("Jon", m$Name) | m$Name2, ] but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 distinct possibilities for the placement of the name you are searching for in the list of names:

1. It is the only name in the list of names
2. It is the first of several names in the list of names
3. It is the last of several names in the list of names
4. It is somewhere in the middle of the list of names

Hence you can use `grepl` with a match string that matches the name if it's in any of those particular positions:

```
Name  <-  c("Jon,Ryan, Lilly",
            "Carol, Ben, Peter",
            "Ben, Carol, Billy",
            "Felix, Jon, Casper")

grepl('(^\\s*Jon,)|(,\\s*Jon,)|(,\\s*Jon\\s*$)|(^\\s*Jon\\s*$)',Name)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

which you can generalize like so:

```
includesName <- function(name,x)
    grepl(paste0('(^\\s*',name,',)|(,\\s*',name,',)|(,\\s*',name,'\\s*$)|(^\\s*',name,'\\s*$)'),
          x)
includesName('Jon',Name)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

The use of `\s' is to allow for white space that may be included between the names or at the end of the list (especially if these data were stored in a database with fixed width character columns, or in the case of being hand entered).

The reason for matching each of the scenarios explicitly is (rather than `"(Jon$)|(Jon,)"` is to match the full name, so you don't accidentally match "Ron Jon" when you didn't mean to.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. also why would you not just do `m[grep('Jon', m$Name), ]` ?

Comment: I think you need some more parens, and less forced whitespace (OP's example doesn't have spaces). Something like `"(Jon,)|(Jon$)"` shouldn't match Jonathan or Jonah.

Comment: m <- m[grep("Jon", m$Name), ] That worked for me guys! thanks so much but is there a way to generalize your code or the line of code above to include the same conditions but for multiple columns, say for for example there was another column labeled Name2 I tried this m <- m[grep("Jon", m$Name) | m$Name2, ] but it didnt work

Comment: @CyrusM you'd have to do that separately: `m[grepl("Jon", m$Name) | grepl('Jon', m$Name2), ]`

Comment: Sorry for the half baked answer.  I updated the code, which didn't work previously due to a misplaced paren in the call to `grepl`. See the updated response.

Comment: The regex in my solution includes word boundaries. Is that not the more concise way to handle these concerns about `Jon`'s location within the string?

Comment: @jennybryan Your answer is more concise and works just fine as long as names are valid regex names, which is not the case for hyphenated names ("Mary-Beth"), initials ("J.D."), people who go by two names ("Ron Jon") etc.   In the provided example, all the names were valid regex words, whereas I chose to rely on the delimiters rather than the content of the names, which *might* be more accurate when dealing with 100,000+ records.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great task for [dplyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html), especially given the size of your real data. I create a `tbl_df` for your `m` which is basically a data.frame. I'm including a second name-based variable, since you asked about that. I create a custom function to search for the string `Jon`. Then use `mutate_each()` to search within the name variables, then filter on the results to return just the rows that are hits.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

m <- data_frame(Name1 = c('Jon,Ryan,Lilly', 'Carol,Ben,Peter',
                         'Ben,Carol,Billy', 'Felix,Jon,Casper'),
                Name2 = c('Susie,Jenny,Katy', 'Nigel,Ian,Jon',
                          'Nigel, Jenny', 'Ryan, Lilly, Ben'),
                Event = 'Soccer',
                Duration = c(3, 6, 5, 3))
m
# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

#              Name1            Name2  Event Duration
# 1   Jon,Ryan,Lilly Susie,Jenny,Katy Soccer        3
# 2  Carol,Ben,Peter    Nigel,Ian,Jon Soccer        6
# 3  Ben,Carol,Billy     Nigel, Jenny Soccer        5
# 4 Felix,Jon,Casper Ryan, Lilly, Ben Soccer        3

jon_fun <- function(x) str_detect(x, '\\bJon\\b')

m %>%
  mutate_each(funs(jon_fun), jon1 = Name1, jon2 = Name2) %>%
  filter(jon1 | jon2) %>%
  select(-starts_with('jon'))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

#              Name1            Name2  Event Duration
# 1   Jon,Ryan,Lilly Susie,Jenny,Katy Soccer        3
# 2  Carol,Ben,Peter    Nigel,Ian,Jon Soccer        6
# 3 Felix,Jon,Casper Ryan, Lilly, Ben Soccer        3
```